# Scan Library for music track

Tags: podcast

Hope, I got the right forum for my question.

I'm a Podcaster and publishing podcasts since 2005. In my first few episodes I used a Music Track as an opener which seems to have a copyright on it, so I got a mail from a lawyer. First of all: Yep, i didn't check the license in detail so I have to pay for this now. I appreciate the work of musicians and I never wanted to do piracy - the website I got the track from seemed to have free tracks and so I used them.

Anyway: I have to commit myself to never ever republish this copyrighted track again. But in The mass of episodes I have created it would be hard work to check of I used the track even after changing the opener to a (real) free track. Is there a possibility to scan my library automatically against a short part of the copyrighted track?

If this is the wrong section, please refer to the correct one.

Thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: What OS are you on? What format are your podcasts in?

Comment: I' m using Windows7. But I can also use a Linux Distribution if it's really needed. But Windows is preferred.

Comment: Sorry, was on mobile, didn't See your Second question: I'm using MP3 as Format.

Answer (score 1):

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/match-two-sounds-with-a-level-of-certainty/5344#5344

Similar post, but the conclustion was that while the technology exists, it is mainly used to confirm what a song is etc...but you could for sure look into the Shazam or Soundhound APIs to see if you can create a code/script that would do it for you

However if the song, has a point in which the song is literally the only thing playing, you could use a software called pluraleyes, to sync your podcasts to that song, if they find a sync point, most likely it will be that song...

This may or may not work to some degree, there is obviously a high level of error while trying to make it match, the more of the song playing that is not mixed with anything else, the higher the likelyness of this working.

Comment: Pluraleyes is not available for Windows [yet](http://www.redgiantsoftware.com/news/featured/pluraleyes-3-faq/)

Comment: Additionally Pluraleyes is a kind of expensive. Of course: Compared to a fine it's perhaps cheap. But there has to be a less expensive method, I think.
I have several seconds in the podcast without any voice on it, so I am quite sure, that if there is a matching tool out there it would have easy work...

Comment: This is the only matching software that I know of, there is a free trial